# Javaw.exe running when starting eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javaw

Whenever I launch eclipse, javaw.exe automatically starts and is displayed in the list of processes in the task manager. How does javaw.exe automatically start on launching eclipse? Can it be due to some virus or some configuration in eclipse is required for that? It didn't happen earlier. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not virus. javaw.exe is similar to java.exe. It is a Win32 GUI application. This is provided as a helper so that application launches its own GUI window and will not launch a console.

Eclipse uses its own GUI and hence it uses javaw process. So when you click on eclipse.exe it launches eclipse using javaw process.

Just to add a little more explanation - instead of running eclipse.exe, try executing following command.

```
java -jar <Eclipse HOME Directory>plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

Here the console will be locked until the eclipse is running.

Now if you use javaw instead -

```
javaw -jar <Eclipse HOME Directory>plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

You should see same eclipse getting opened. But notice that the console window is freed. You can continue using the console for some other purpose.

Eclipse.exe uses the latter.

Comment: Some of the wording is nearly identical to this [link](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-vs-javaw-vs-javaws/) which offers a more detailed explanation:

Comment: It is a rarity I downvote. But the reasoning was that when I read the first and second paragraph I had the distinct impression it was two different authors. When I searched for the 4th sentence I found it word for word identical to the article. Your third sentence is identical. and the second sentence is identical except the word `very` doesn't appear. If you indeed used this articles wording (and if you aren't the author of the article), I think that an appropriate link to the source material may be a good idea.